# Getting "Permission Denied" when using saveAsync with Outlook requirement set 1.6 - only for the users own events

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We got a working Outlook Add-in that uses [saveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-1.6#outlook-office-messagecompose-saveasync-member(1)) to get the current item id in some cases, usually works fine, but we encountered an edge case we cannot solve:

Some users have M365 with Outlook 16 (Office 2019), build number 16.0.10382.20010, with requirement set 1.6 where we encounter the problem.

- The Add-in works fine from Outlook on the Web
- The Add-in works fine for Outlook 16 (Office 365), build number 16.0.14729.2019 (requirement set 1.8+)
- The Add-in does not work for Outlook 16 (Office 2019) build number 16.0.10382.20010 (highest requirement set supported here is 1.6)

  - This error only happen for events/items the user did create himself. For events someone else created, where he got invited, the function returns the result and item id just fine.

Response from saveAsync:

```
{
"description":"Permission denied",
"number":-2146828218,"stack":
"Error: Permission denied\n   at b.prototype.execute (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js:20:98268)\n   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js:20:187519)\n   at z (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js:20:187490)\n   at H (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js:20:187044)\n   at U (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js:20:186043)\n   at Zr (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js:20:242447)\n   at getItemIdAsync"}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest posting this to the OfficeJS repo at github instead.

Comment: Ok, posted it here again https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2360